# Azure service bus with azure functions advantages

Tags: azure-functions, azureservicebus

What are the advantages of using azure service bus to listen and/or publish messages with azure functions compare to using service bus without functions?

Answer (score 1):

AFAIK,

- By building message topologies with complex routing, Azure Service Bus simplifies complex messaging workflows. This Azure Function Service Bus allows you to send messages to a large number of subscribers and distribute them to downstream systems at scale.
- When a message arrives in a queue, the Azure Function Service Bus Queue Trigger hits and does some functionality like Data Processing, etc.

It means, Azure Functions has great functionalities when integrated with Service Bus.

1. Functions will react (hitting the trigger) when a queue or topic message is created in the service bus and does some data processing (whatever the custom we write in the function).
2. Azure Functions also acts as sender to send the messages to queues.

- As written in this [blog by Wolfgang](https://www.programmingwithwolfgang.com/azure-functions-process-queue-messages/),

> Azure Functions are great when you want to execute for background services like processing items on queues but it is not that great when users are waiting for the result because it might take some time to start the function.

- As stated in the [Blog of 3Cloudsolutions](https://3cloudsolutions.com/post/reliable-messaging-with-azure-functions-and-service-bus/) by the author K Osborne (Lorne Hubenthal),

> Do you want to include messaging into your solution in a matter of minutes and with minimal code?

- Azure Functions and the Service Bus can help you transfer messages between applications and other services more easily.

Answer (score 1):

It worthwhile mentioning two important points regarding your question:

1- ***Cost saving***: Azure functions are serverless computing. That is, you pay only for the execution time your code spend running. Otherwise you will not be charged at all :)

2- ***Scalability***: If your service bus has lots of data, you can easily make use of Azure scaling options to handle all that traffic.